# Rewrite Rule to expect dots

Tags: regex, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I use this RewriteRule in my .htaccess

```
RewriteRule ^api/v1/([A-Za-z0-9-_,]+)$ api/v1/index.php?function=$1
```

I have tried several variations already, but I was unable to find a way to include dots into the regex expression.

Some sources here on SO, say that I can simply include **"."** right after my **","** but some sources say I need to escape the dot with **"."** Neither has unfortunately worked so far.

Comment: What are you actually trying to do though? Can you provide an example of a URL and what you expect it to be rewritten to?

Comment: I need to make a request /api/v1/55.5464 I could send this parameters via [POST] however in this case a [GET] parameter is what I am looking for.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can include dot in character class inside `[..]` however there are few issues with your rule:

1. Hyphen must be at first or last position to avoid escaping.
2. By including dot your pattern will also match `index.php` and since `mod_rewrite` runs in a loop it will make `function` query parameter as `index.php`. To avoid this situation you will need `RewriteCond`.
3. `[a-zA-Z0-9_]` can be replaced with `[\w]`

Try this rule:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^api/v1/([\w,.-]+)/?$ api/v1/index.php?function=$1 [L,QSA,NC]
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems you simply need to add dot without escaping

When I have the following files:

```
// .htaccess

RewriteEngine On

RewriteRule ^api/v1/([A-Za-z0-9-_,.]+)$ api/v1/index.php?function=$1 [QSA]
```

and

```
// api/v1/index.php

<?php

var_dump($_GET['function']);
```

and I run url `http://mydomain/api/v1/something.more.something` in my browser I get the following result:

`string(24) "something.more.something"`

so the whole match is passed to `$_GET['function']`.

It seems to work without any problem (as you see there's also dot inside the url and it is working)

Comment: yes I have tried. as soon as I make that change, the request completely fails to return any data at all

Comment: @ahojvole Pleasee look again at my answer. I completely changed it. It seems to work without any problem now.

Comment: Thank you for effort. anubhava's solution worked for me for the reason he explains